# ORA-39125 during schema export

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Today, I was trying to do export with expdp on Linux 64, Oracle10g:

```
$ expdp system/manager parfile='datapump/dumps/exp_schema.par'
```

where exp_schema is:

```
directory=DPDUMP
dumpfile=prod_exp_APPROOT.dmp
schemas=APPROOT
content=ALL
```

and getting an error:

```
ORA-39125: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.UNLOAD_METADATA while calling DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_XML_CLOB [TABLE_DATA:"APPROOT"."SED_OUTDOC"]
ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails:
BEGIN "SYS"."DBMS_SCHED_EXPORT_CALLOUTS".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,1,1,'10.02.00.01.00'); END;
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 907
ORA-31603: object "SCHEDULER$_PROGRAM_ARG" of type TABLE not found in schema "APPROOT"

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6241

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x368fb4540     14916  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0x368fb4540      6300  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0x368fb4540      2340  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0x368fb4540      6861  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0x368fb4540      1262  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0x3704b4270         2  anonymous block

Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_04" stopped due to fatal error at 16:57:57
```

I don't understand what's wrong..

Comment: This looks like the behaviour referred to in Oracle Support note 1109045.1. Is there a DDL trigger protecting the `APPROOT` schema?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Alex! Yes, I have 2 DDL triigers in other schema for audit (FGA_OWNER). I've disabled both and it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the behaviour referred to in Oracle Support note 1109045.1, and suggests a DDL trigger that is, perhaps, preventing objects owned by `APPROOT` from being dropped. Something simple like this would cause the error you're seeing, I believe, though I don't have a DB at the right patch level to test it:

```
create or replace trigger block_drop
before drop on schema
begin
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Nope');
end;
/
```

The support note suggests it affects 10.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.1, so presumbaly the behaviour has changed in later patchsets.